# Check if two lines (each with start-end positions) overlap in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have the following two sets of position each correspond to the start and end position:

```
line T: t1-t2   (t1 = start_pos, t2 = end_pos)
line S: s1-s2   (s1 = start_pos, t2 = end_pos)
```

I want to write the algorithm in Python to check if T intersect with S.

**Example 1:**

```
   t1-t2=55-122 and s1-s2=58-97
          s1------------s2
        t1-----------------t2
    This should return True
```

**Example 2:**

```
 t1-t2=4-66 / t1-t2=143-166  and s1-s2=80-141
        s1----s2
 t1--t2          t1---t2
Both instances of T should return False
```

But why this code failed:

```
def is_overlap(pos, dompos):
    """docstring for is_overlap"""
    t1,t2 = [int(x) for x in pos.split("-")]
    s1,s2 = [int(x) for x in dompos.split("-")]

    # Here we define the instance of overlapness
    if (t1 >= s1 and t2 >= s2) or \
       (t1 >= s1 and t2 <= s2) or \
       (t1 <= s1 and t2 >= s2) or \
       (t1 <= s1 and t2 <= s2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

which output this:

```
In [2]: is_overlap('55-122', '58-97')
Out[2]: True

In [3]: is_overlap('4-66', '80-141')
Out[3]: True

In [4]: is_overlap('143-166', '80-141')
Out[4]: True
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider a span `[a, b]` and another span `[x, y]`. They either overlap or they are separate.

If they are separate, one of two things must be true:

- `[a, b]` is to the left of `[x, y]`, or
- `[x, y]` is to the left of `[a, b]`.

If `[a, b]` is to the left of `[x, y]`, we have `b < x`.

If `[x, y]` is to the left of `[a, b]`, we have `y < a`.

If neither of these is true, the spans cannot be separate. They must overlap.

This logic is implemented in the following function.

```
def are_separate(r, s):  # r and s are ordered pairs
  (a, b) = r
  (x, y) = s
  if b < x or y < a:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

More concisely:

```
def are_separate(r, s):
  (a, b) = r
  (x, y) = s
  return b < x or y < a
```

Even more concisely:

```
def are_separate(r, s):
  return r[1] < s[0] or s[1] < r[0]
```

If you want the contrary function, `are_overlapping`, just negate the expression:

```
def are_overlapping(r, s):
  return not(r[1] < s[0] or s[1] < r[0])
```

Which is logically equivalent to:

```
def are_overlapping(r, s):
  return r[1] >= s[0] and s[1] >= r[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who want two lines in two dimensions, @michael's answer is not enough. The following code is based on the equation found in the Wikipedia page listed just above the code as well as a little Pythagoras to check the intersection lies between the appropriate points. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = 200, 200, 300, 300
x3, y3, x4, y4 = 200, 150, 300, 350

px = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / \
     ((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4))
py = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / \
     ((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4))

if ((x1 - px) ** 2 + (y1 - py) ** 2) ** 0.5 + ((x2 - px) ** 2 + (y2 - py) ** 2) ** 0.5 == \
        ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5 and \
        ((x3 - px) ** 2 + (y3 - py) ** 2) ** 0.5 + ((x4 - px) ** 2 + (y4 - py) ** 2) ** 0.5 == \
        ((x3 - x4) ** 2 + (y3 - y4) ** 2) ** 0.5:
    print("Overlap at point: (%s, %s)" % (px, py))
else:
    print("No overlap.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are wrong; check them again. For instance, the first condition implies that `(t_1, t_2) = (100, 200)` and `(s_1, s_2) = (50, 60)` to be a valid set of overlapping lines. But clearly, they aren't.

Something else you might want to consider is if the user inputs the coordinates in backwards. What if he puts in something like `'80-30'`?